# Trying to write a PHP template class - this feels wrong

Tags: php, templates

I'm trying to learn a few things about PHP and write my own template class. But it just feels ineffective. Wouldn't performance take a hit from doing this? If you can, take a look and see what's wrong:

```
<?

class Template {

    private $file, $template, $data;

    public function __construct($file) {
            $this->template = file_get_contents('views/wrapper.php');
            $this->file = file_get_contents('views/'.$file.'.php');
    }

    public function __set($key, $val) { $this->data[$key] = $val; }

    public function __get($key) { return $this->data[$key]; }

    private function replaceAll() {
        foreach($this->data AS $key => $val)
            $this->template = str_replace('@'.$key, $val, $this->template);
        $this->template = str_replace('{LOAD}', $this->file, $this->template);
    }

    public function render() {
        $this->replaceAll();
        echo $this->template;
    }
}

?>
```

I want to use a wrapper, that holds the footer + header, which contain a sidebar/navigation. So I'll need to somehow dynamically set an active class there, and then I want to be able to load the view based on the constructor or something similar. Is what I'm doing.. okay?

Comment: Exactly, why are you writing a template class at all? :P

Comment: Magic methods will give you a very hard time debugging in the future.

Comment: @boltclock experimentation, mainly. I'm working on a semi-large project and was told that templating would be best rather than singletons, and other class usage.. Lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

__get and __set functions are very slow. string replacements are pretty slow as well. why are you making your template in this way? what if you did something more like this?

**template class**

```
class template {

   protected $templateFile;

   public function __construct($template_file) {
      $this->templateFile = $template_file;
   }

   public function render() {
      require($this->templateFile);
   }
}
```

**template file**

```
<html>
   <p><?= $this->someProperty ?></p>
</html>
```

**usage**

```
$view = new template($template_file_path);
$view->someProperty = 'hello world';
$view->render();
```

only drawback would be that whoever writes the templates would also have access to writing PHP.

Comment: I rewrote it here: https://github.com/OutThisLife/Time-Journal/blob/master/classes/template.class.php -- still using get/set for dynamic elements. thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You want your template parser to be generic, so no static files like your wrapper.php! If you want to look at building a simple template parser i recommend this:

http://www.broculos.net/en/article/how-make-simple-html-template-engine-php